# Using TortoiseSVN to Merge Feature Branch Prior to SVN 1.5

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branching-and-merging

I'm using Subversion 1.3 or 1.4. I can't upgrade my server to 1.5 yet. I've created a branch, made changes, and now need to merge it back into the trunk since I've finished working on my branch.

In the time since I branched (~one month), many changes hit the trunk. I have merged those into my branch using SVN's "merge revisions" feature. This means that the branch contains the latest trunk code, along with my changes.

I can't use the Tortoise SVN "reintegrate branch" feature, since I don't have 1.5. I tried merging the revision range of the branch into the trunk, but I get **tons** of conflicts (and tree conflicts). I'm not sure why, since my branch has merged all the changes from the trunk (rebased).

I did some restructuring (moving files around, creating/deleting directories). I feel like I'm missing something; if my branch has the latest trunk code plus the branch changes, why is the merge back to trunk full of conflicts?

How can I quickly/easily merge my updated branch back to the trunk?

Comment: I think updating my branch to the latest code from the trunk was a mistake. I'm getting tons of conflicts like "the last merged added X, but you already have it added" or "the last merge deleted X, but yours is already deleted."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Referring to the [SVN Redbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re16.html), prior to 1.5, the way to merge changes back to trunk is to specify the revision number prior to the branch explicitly.  Quoting the relevant section...

> Merge a branch back into the trunk
>   (assuming that you have a working copy
>   of the trunk, and that the branch was
>   created in revision 250):

```
$ svn merge -r 250:HEAD http://svn.red-bean.com/repos/branches/my-branch
```

Also, this needs to be done from the working copy of the trunk and not the branch. Perhaps this is what is causing the conflicts you have mentioned.

Comment: I was merging the branch into the trunk, merging from the working copy of the trunk. Discounting the fact that I mentioned TortoiseSVN (while you mentioned SVN), this still doesn't explain the reintegration process -- or why a fully-integrated latest-version branch merges into trunk with conflicts.

Comment: @ashes999  TortoiseSVN uses svn command underneath so the answer applies. Prior to 1.5, subversion does not keep track of the merges done. Thus reintegration is trickier.  http://svn.haxx.se/tsvnusers/archive-2008-07/0446.shtml may give some ideas

Comment: For the record, The downvote on this answer is not mine.
However this will most likely not work, because between 250 and HEAD, there will have been a commit from a merge from trunk.That change will attempt to be applied again (wrongly) to Trunk, causing a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why Raghuram's answer is accepted.

This describes how to merge feature branches back into trunk and retire them in version 1.4

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.commonuses.patterns.feature